# Oracle RESTRICTED SESSION error

Tags: oracle

I tried to install Oracle database 12c on my machine following the documentation:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/Windows_DB_Install_OBE/Installing_Oracle_Db12c_Windows.html

I have successfully installed the database itself and can login to the database pdborcl using:

```
sqlplus sys/Oracle_1@pdborcl as sysdba
```

I unlocked the hr user following the instruction using:

```
alter user hr identified by hr account unlock;
```

However, when I tried to connect to the database using the newly unlocked user: hr, it gives an error message:

```
SQL> connect hr/hr@pdborcl
ERROR:
ORA-01035: ORACLE only available to users with RESTRICTED SESSION privilege.

Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
```

Can someone let me know how to solve this problem? Is this something with licensing?

**UPDATE:**

I actually tried:

```
alter system disable restricted session;
```

What I get is:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65144: ALTER SYSTEM DISABLE RESTRICTED SESSION is not permitted.
```

The query: `select logins from v$instance` returns:

```
LOGINS
---------
ALLOWED
```

Comment: First hit on Google
 https://community.oracle.com/message/9325774

Comment: It feels like something went wrong during the installation.  This should not have happened.

Comment: Could be this bug http://askdba.org/weblog/2015/07/12-1-0-2-pdb-fails-to-come-out-of-restricted-mode/

Answer (score 6):

If `alter system disable restricted session` doesn't work it means that there are patch violations

Check the status with below command:

```
select * from PDB_PLUG_IN_VIOLATIONS;
```

If post steps did not complete properly then it will keep PBD's in restricted mode. Run the below steps:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

shutdown immediate
startup upgrade
alter pluggable database all open upgrade;
quit
cd $ORACLE_HOME/OPatch
./datapatch -verbose
```

check the log, should be no errors

```
sql> shutdown immediate
sql>startup 
sql> alter pluggable database all open;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below Steps. Hope its useful for you

Few days back it worked in this way for me

```
SQL> select logins from v$instance;

    LOGINS
    ----------
    RESTRICTED

SQL> alter system disable restricted session;

    System altered.

SQL> select logins from v$instance;

    LOGINS
    ----------
    ALLOWED
```

If won't work try this Post restart of the Database Server

Comment: you need to do it with sysdba user. Have you tried restarting DB server?

Answer (score 2):

Check if your PDB is in restricted mode by entering `show pdbs`. If under Restricted it says YES, then you have to just shut down the instance and start it up again. Here's how:

```
SQL> shutdown immediate

Pluggable Database closed.

SQL> startup

Pluggable Database opened.

SQL> show pdbs

CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
------ ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
     3 PDBORCL                        READ WRITE NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database was opened with restricted session. 
As sysdba run the following command to dissable restrcited session option:

```
alter system disable restricted session;
```

Comment: Kevin, try below link and you will get some idea..

http://askdba.org/weblog/2015/07/12-1-0-2-pdb-fails-to-come-out-of-restricted-mode/

Answer (score -4):

```
grant connect to user;

grant all privileges to user;
```

Comment: No, this won't solve this particular problem.